# Where is this location in the Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

[image: the witcher enjoying a break in the sun]

I took the screen shot while playing the Witcher 3 a few years back, but forgot to note where it was, and would like to go back to experiment some more.  It was along the coast and there was several ships similar to the one on the image, that had stranded on the beach.

Anyone recognize the location?

---

EDIT:  The accepted answer was completely correct, and I moved a bit ahead in the restarted story to get there.  The trees mentioned in the supplementary answer are just behind the camera. I went back to the old version (which hides as a beta) but the number of trees were the same.

However the monitor I played the game on at the time is wider than a normal 1920x1080 monitor which is why there is more scenery to the sides.   It is tricky because the time between the stern(?) being fully lit and shadows from the trees being cast on it is rather short.   It looks beautiful though when the sun sets.

[image: sunset lighting the stern]

Comment: Can't confirm but my first thought is somewhere in skellige. The statue's style feels more viking than much of the art in velen, and the cliffs feel more sheer than the mainland.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe in the background I can see the town of [Rannvaig](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Rannvaig).  Looking at the map, Rannvaig is the red circle in this image of the Skellige map:

[image: rannvaig]

I also see an island in the background which would also be next to Rannvaig.  You appear to be on a cliff side, so looking at the map geography, I believe you are where the blue circle is.

Comment: I am very impressed.  Will you share how your line of thought was?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen First I just looked at a map of Skellige on IGN for the game and deduced using the map a rough idea of where you are (the area in your screenshot looks like Skellige, so I started there). The island also helped with determining this.  I saw in the background the building in Rannvaig, and I looked at the game Wiki page for the town which had a picture of said building. Then I basically scanned over the map and took a fairly well educated guess of where you were by putting all this together.

Comment: You can also see a boat docked in your picture, which is also present in the picture of the town on the game Wiki.  This is the picture I am referring to https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/witcher/images/9/9a/Tw3_Rannvaig_2.png/revision/latest?cb=20160524173053

Answer (score 11):

[Timmy Jim's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/401719/222022) is completely correct, but here is some more detailed information:

- The exact location is south-west of Crossroads, looking across the bay towards the area between Rannvaig and Fayrlund:

  [image]
- Since the Next-gen Update (Patch 4.0), some trees have apparently been added to this area (and all over the game world, I guess), obstructing your original vantage point:

  [image]
- Your screenshot was taken at around 18.00 (at Dusk), as only at that point will the ship's bow be lit from this side.
- That weird patch of dark and light grey shapes on the right just above the cliff in the OP's screenshot is a flock of birds:

  [image]

  I think they gather at that point in the OP's screenshot during their animation loop (possibly their spawn point?).

Comment: Thank you for actually going there to confirm the location.  I downloaded the game again to go there myself, but had forgotten that finishing the game offered a restart with your current inventory which I had accepted so I apparently need to play for quite a bit yet  so, thanks for verifying the location!

Comment: Got to skellige, it is right where Geralt washed ashore after getting the boat ride there and there is a lot of trees and bushes just as you said,