# Where in Skellige is this shipwreck located?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I wanted to find a shipwreck in Witcher 3's Skellige for purposes of a Witcher Tabletop RPG campaign I'm playing, and I found these images of one:

[image]

[image]

[image]

While these images are nice, what they don't tell me is the ship's location. I would look for it myself, but unfortunately all my saves disappeared when I updated to the next-gen version of Witcher 3, which means I'd have to replay enough of the game to get all the way to Skellige to begin looking for it. I tried figuring it out by looking at the minimap shown in image 3 and using [witcher3map.com](http://witcher3map.com), but I couldn't find any matching spot. I'm guessing the minimap and the big map may be rotated differently.

As such, I ask, where could this shipwreck be located? Either a link to [witcher3map.com](http://witcher3map.com) with the coordinates set or a description using the relative proximity of more easily findable locations like named villages is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recall, this is the "starting area" of when you first arrive to Skellige.  It is around here:

[image: shipwreck area]

This is just to the southwest of the "Crossroads" fast travel icon.

Images found on [this guide](https://www.ign.com/wikis/the-witcher-3-wild-hunt/Destination:_Skellige) show the minimap and it corresponds to here.

[Here is a link to the Monster Nest that is at the ship wreck](https://witcher3map.com/s/#6/-28.217/-35.431/m=-23.544,-37.551). If I also remember right, its a Siren monster nest.

Comment: Somewhat ironically is [another post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401679/where-is-this-location-in-the-witcher-3) asking where this area is too (almost), except they were trying to find some red statue thing that just so happen is in the vicinity.